# bash: Installing Ruby Version Manager from git repository. How does this bash command work?

Tags: bash

I am installing Ruby on Ubuntu 10.10 using this [guide](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) and came across the following command to install [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) (Ruby Version Manager):

`$ bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )`

Can anybody explain how this bash command works, i.e. the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<( command )` is known as [Process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html). In this case it feeds the output of `curl` into the stdin of `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

When bash sees `command1 <( command2 )`, it runs `command2` and captures its standard output.  It then makes that output available from a named file and passes the name of that file on the command line of `command1`.  So your example,

```
bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )
```

gets translated to:

```
bash < some_file
```

where `some_file` contains the output of the `curl` command.  On Linux `some_file` tends to be something like `/dev/fd/63`, because bash has created a pipe internally and is passing the read end of the pipe on file descriptor 63.

As far as I can tell, this whole construct is a roundabout way of saying:

```
curl etc. etc. | bash
```

and has the same result.  I'm not sure why the author didn't just use the pipe form instead.

See the link in @dogbane's answer for more info, including cases where it's actually useful.